# Git : Determine if branch is in a merge conflict state

Tags: git, bash

I am writing a bash script to do some automation. Part of the script involves navigating to a local repo, switching to the local master branch, then pulling the remote master to update the local master branch with the latest code.

Does anyone know if there's a way I can programatically determine if the pull resulted in a merge conflict so that I can bail at that point and not execute the rest of the script?

Any help / info is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use the `--ff-only` to force `merge`/`pull` to error if they would cause a conflict (or otherwise cannot fast-forward merge)?

Comment: Does --ff-only cause a non-zero return I can check for? I have to catch it so I can bail out of the script and not just the merge.

Comment: Did you check the man page? `--ff-only Refuse to merge and exit with a non-zero status...`

Comment: Depending on the situation, I prefer the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783114/13773246 (check for the existence of `.git/MERGE_HEAD`). In particular `git ls-files -u` will be empty if conflicts are resolved and added to the index but not yet committed, while `MERGE_HEAD` exists until the resolved conflicts are committed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `git ls-files -u`.  It prints unmerged files.  If it prints nothing, there are no unmerged files.

However, while that's a direct answer for the question you asked "as asked", using `git pull` in a script is a bit dicey: `pull` is a convenience script that runs `fetch` for you, and then (depending on how you direct it and/or have configured your repo) runs either `merge` or `rebase` for you.  Given that you are writing a script that has a particular goal in mind, you should most likely be using lower-level commands that do more-specific things.  For instance, you might use `git fetch` followed by (as Etan Reisner suggested in a comment) `git merge --ff-only` so as to *never* attempt a merge.

Comment: For what the script does, I don't want to avoid a merge if there's a conflict. I want the merge to occur and then determine if there was a conflict with the merge.

Comment: OK, in that case I'd still suggest doing `git fetch` and a direct `git merge`; you can then inspect the exit status of the merge step.  It does not seem to be well-documented and I'm not sure if the `ls-files -u` method might be safer, but `git merge` actually exits 0 on no-conflicts, 1 on conflicts.

Comment: In my experience playing around with it just now for a script I'm writing, `git merge` just encountered a conflict and exited with a 127 code, leaving the repo in merging state

Answer (score 28):

Based on the answer given by torek, here is a ready-to-use snippet:

```
CONFLICTS=$(git ls-files -u | wc -l)
if [ "$CONFLICTS" -gt 0 ] ; then
   echo "There is a merge conflict. Aborting"
   git merge --abort
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This lists files with a merge conflict:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Answer (score 0):

`git config --global user.email "Email Id"   && git config --global user.name "User Name"   && git merge  --no-commit  --no-ff origin/master   && git diff --cached   && git merge --abort`

This code is combination of multiple steps.

1. Starting a merge with no-commit and no-ff.
2. Fetching differences in both branch.
3. Aborting the merge

When there will be any conflict it will fail at second step and you will get merge conflict error as output , else you will get difference in both branch.

For details you can go to [GIT-SCM](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) documentation