# How to determine if Git merge is in process

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a Git command that can be used to determine if a merge is in-process (i.e. uncommitted)?  I know I can simply check for `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, but is this proper and/or **future-proof** for command-line scripts?

Comment: you can use git status

Comment: I would need to use the `--porcelain` option to guarantee future-proofness, at which point I would need to parse the output for...?

Comment: @NickVolynkin A command whose functionality is guaranteed not to change in newer versions of Git.

Comment: @NickVolynkin See my answer.  This is the solution I have currently settled on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

One trick is to use a Git command that will fail if a merge is in progress.  You can then check the return code of the command.  You'll also want to make sure that the command will not affect your working copy or index in the event that it succeeds.  While there are many commands that fall into this category, one that seems appropriate is

```
git merge HEAD
```

which returns a 128 code if a merge is in progress, but 0 otherwise.  Note that when a merge is not in-process, this command will simply print *Already up-to-date* since you are just merging with yourself.  So, for scripting purposes, you can do this (in BASH)

```
git merge HEAD &> /dev/null
result=$?
if [ $result -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Merge in progress."
else
    echo "Merge not in progress."
fi
```

Note that even with the `--quiet` flag of `git merge`, an in-process merge will still cause this command to print to the error stream.  This is why I redirect its output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: This is quite clever.

Comment: `git merge` returns `1` when merge couldn't be finished, either because of conflicts, or because of a typo, e.g. `git merge origin/mater`

Comment: What a smelly hack! And this is the top answer? Does this approach work when a rebase or some other Git workflow is in progress? Will this be so in future versions of Git?

Comment: Nice advice. I used `git merge --continue`

Answer (score 20):

You can safely check for the existence of `MERGE_HEAD` in your git directory[1] to determine whether there's a merge in progress.  The `MERGE_HEAD` file contains the commit ids that are being merged in, that will be the `n`th parents of the committed merge.  For example, if I try to merge branch `br1` which is at `c085e0c`:

```
> git merge --no-ff --no-commit br1
Automatic merge went well; stopping before committing as requested

> cat .git/MERGE_HEAD
c085e0caa2598064bfde9cc6318bd2c73fee2371
```

If you are doing an octopus merge, then you will see more than one commit id in this file (newline separated):

```
> git merge --no-ff --no-commit br2 br3
Fast-forwarding to: br2
Trying simple merge with br3
Automatic merge went well; stopping before committing as requested

> cat .git/MERGE_HEAD
69b0169b1cba60de86161b375f013c59ad9581d8
99dad0187351d61ae8e88d49c96d7383f9e8fa6d
```

Using `MERGE_HEAD` is actually [how git clients determine whether there's a merge in progress](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/585b5dacc7f440a163c20117cfa35fb714a7ba7b/src/repository.c#L2733).  Some provide this insight through leaky abstractions:

```
> git merge --abort
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

So checking for the presence of `MERGE_HEAD` is perfectly acceptable and is is as future proof as anything in software - meaning that any changes to `git-merge` would have to take compatibility with other git clients into account and would (hopefully!) gracefully transition and/or provide backward compatibility.

[1] You can trust the existence of `MERGE_HEAD` much more than you can trust that `.git` is underneath your working directory.  Somebody could use the `--git-dir` flag or the `GIT_DIR` environment variable.

Comment: Looks like this is one of the most future-proof methods.

Comment: The github link unfortunately points to master, so now it doesn't make sense. Still, grepping that file for merge_head does show usages.

Answer (score 14):

Since `MERGE_HEAD` is only available during a merge and is also future-proof, we can simply use `git rev-list -1 MERGE_HEAD` (conveniently, a plumbing command) which will exit with code 128 if `MERGE_HEAD` is not found. Pipe stdout and stderr to `/dev/null` for a cleaner check. Or even better, use `git rev-parse -q --verify MERGE_HEAD`.

Comment: This, I belive, is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image: git status]

you can run 

`git status`

git will tell you what happening in your repository.

E.g. 
 * conflicting files (unmerged files)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's tough to tell from a porcelain command whether you're merging or not.  You would have to look for "All conflicts fixed but you are still merging" *and* "You have unmerged paths".  (And hopefully nothing else!)

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to test for the presence of a `.git/MERGE_MSG` file.

That is because, *before* 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017), you can end up in a situation where you do *not* have `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, even though the merge is in progress.

See [commit 9d89b35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d89b35526b54c3ba33371b184a1ba6e30f8f46f), [commit 8e6a6bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e6a6bb36037da87ac98da280459269168b9f525), [commit 62dc42b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62dc42b9370b123924ba3423d51976e78d13a924) (23 Aug 2017), and [commit e2de82f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e2de82f27128441278da979ef101239c40188064) (21 Aug 2017) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6e6ba65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e6ba65a7c8f8f9556ec42678f661794d47f7f98), 27 Aug 2017)</sup>

> Killing "`git merge --edit`" before the editor returns control left
>   the repository in a state with `MERGE_MSG` but without `MERGE_HEAD`,
>   which incorrectly tells the subsequent "`git commit`" that there was
>   a squash merge in progress.
>   This has been fixed.

After Git 2.14.x/2.15, that won't be the case anymore, and testing for `.git/MERGE_HEAD` will be enough.