# Using git as part of an automated script - pausing the script for a rebase

Tags: git, bash

I'm using git as part of a script automating a file patch. It goes something like this:

```
cd "$gitdir"
git checkout original
monodis "$original_dll" > "$ilfname"
git add "$ilfname"
git commit -m "$(date +"%s")"
git checkout modded
git rebase original

# More code here
```

As you can probably guess - this disassembles a .NET dll and applies a few patches by way of git.

But what happens if there's a merge conflict? Is there a way to "Pause" the script until the rebase is completed?

Comment: I'm on a computer that has neither git nor bash installed, but you might be able to leverage the exit status of the `git rebase` command. I _think_ it's nonzero if there's a merge conflict, but I could be wrong.

Comment: See this: [How to determine if Git merge is in process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30733415/2790048)

Comment: ssdecontrol, Nick: Wouldn't that require me to start a loop with a delay and check over and over whether the merge was done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split your script in two, the first part calling the second one upon a conflict-less rebase. In case of manual intervention needed the operator would call the second part after completing the merge.